# GNU Octave octave.vim syntax file auto indent not working

Tags: vimrc, neovim, syntax-highlighting

Before introducing the octave syntax file in `~/.config/nvim/syntax/octave.vim` from [here](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3600&quot) auto-indent worked as expected.

After introducing the file, the syntax coloring works, but the auto-indentation does not.

I already read this [remarks](https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html#%3Asyn-file-remarks) and it looks like it should be working.

Does anyone knows what I can do to get auto-indent to work?

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Could you precise what you mean by working? Could you give us example of auto indentation you had and miss? I'm also interested by the following information. Remove the lines you introduced in `init.vim` to get Octave coloring, restart Neovim and give us the result of the following commands `:set ft?` and `:set autoindent?` `:set cindent?` `:set indentexpr?`

Comment: :set ft -> filetype=matlab

Comment: Thanks :-) That is what I was expecting (see my answer).

Comment: Hi thank you. For example, when I do gg=G I expect the whole document to be formatted. Or say I have a for-loop and I press return, I expect the cursor to start in the next line tabbed over by 1. 
filetype=matlab
:set autoindent #returns itself
:set cindent      #returns itself
indentexpr=GetMatlabIndent()

Comment: Thanks for the result but I believe you miss the `?` in my command. The consequence is that you set the option (and then it returns itself). Could you restart Neovim and repeat the commands with the trailing `?` included? I'm already 99% convince that you had matlab auto-indentation that is indeed relatively good for Octave although probably not 100% perfect.

Comment: `filetype=matlab
autoindent
nocindent
indentexpr=GetMatlabIndent()`

I tried your suggestion with the setlocal indentexpr=GetMatlabIndent() did not work. Have not tried the other suggestions yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rik](https://octave.discourse.group/u/rik): At least for Vim, syntax and indentation are two different things handled by two different scripts. I wrote the syntax highlighter for Vim (which should reside in ~/.vim/syntax) and I also wrote an indenter for Vim which which should reside in ~/.vim/indent. The indent file is octave.vim and is attached here. You can probably get it to run on NeoVim easily.

[octave.vim](https://octave.discourse.group/uploads/short-url/7FpLcDKdBSzNXLAI8WQN18JyW4H.vim)

Syntax file from: [octave.vim : Syntax highlighting file for GNU Octave language](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3600)

Anyone with this issue please see the following thread:
https://octave.discourse.group/t/neovim-octave-syntax-highlighting-and-indentation/4228

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is not related to the Octave syntax file. It only introduces syntax coloring properties.

I believe the problem comes with the lines that associate the octave file type to the buffers corresponding to the `*.m` and `*.oct` files:

```
augroup octavedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m,*.oct set filetype=octave
augroup END
```

By default `*.m` files are associated to the `matlab` file type and come with the `matlab` auto-indentation.

With the new lines the octave indentation is reset to your Neovim default indentation.

You can restore it to the `matlab` indentation with the following lines into your `init.vim`:

```
augroup octavetype
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m,*.oct setlocal indentexpr=GetMatlabIndent()
augroup END
```

Or by adding an `octave.vim` file into `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/` with the following content:

```
setlocal indentexpr=GetMatlabIndent()
```

But maybe should we search for a more Octave specific auto-indentation.

Maybe could you consider installing the following plugin [octave](https://github.com/mikea1729/octave.vim) that bring both colorization and Octave specific auto-indentation?

Comment: I just downloaded the plugin with Plug. The syntax highlighting and auto-indentation seems to be working perfectly! Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: You are welcome! If you are fine with the solution could you validate it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It helps the question to rest :-)

Comment: Never mind what you suggested did not solve the problem. I tried each suggestion. When I changed indentexpr to GetMatlabIndent() indentation simply does nothing (breaks formatting completely). When I use the plugin the formatting algorithm doesn't know where: if, for, while etc end, so it keeps on tabbing indefinitely over instead of knowing where the end of the loop is. If you have any suggestions it would be appreciated. I have a couple more things to try, Ill update if I figure it out.